# Stopping onClick from returning the page top the top after jQuery events

Tags: jquery, onclick, return

I've read many posts here regarding this issue, with great solutions, however, none of them seem to work in my case.

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.tab").click(function () {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".inside ul").fadeOut();
        $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("a.tab, h4").FontEffect({
        outline: true
    })
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the assistance.  Now I have the following, tho it is still not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.tab").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".inside ul").fadeOut();
            $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
            var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
            return false;
        });
        //$("a.tab, h4").FontEffect({
        //  outline: true
    //  })
    });
```

ANCHOR TAG:

```
<a href="#" title="content_1" class="tab active">New Videos</a>
```

[VIEWABLE](http://underweardelivery.com)

Comment: @SSHUC dont post code (long code) in a comment, edit your original Q with an update. or if you have found the correct answer, mark it as so

Comment: The page continues to return to the top when the links are clicked.

Comment: what does the anchor tag look like?

Comment: @SSHUC: are you sure your event handler is being fired... does the addClass and fade happen like its supposed to?

Comment: @prodigitalson yes, everything happens great, but once it does, the page then returns to the top

Comment: @Neal I've update the post with the anchor tag

Comment: change the `href='javascript:void(0);'`

Comment: do u have a site where we can see this issue?

Comment: @Neal I have it local, but I'll put it online.  Gimme a few minutes, pls

Comment: @Neal I've placed a link at the end of the post (VIEWABLE)

Comment: @SSHUC try removing the `return false;` see if that does anything

Comment: idk. thats odd. do you have to use anchor tags?

Comment: @Neal do you mean I should remove the href part of the <a>?

Comment: no. why use anchor tags at all? u can use `li`, `div`, `span`, etc etc...

Comment: @Neal ok, let me try that out

Comment: @Neal Ok, thanks for all your help.  I did learn a few things regardless

Comment: you should pick an answer (if one is close to right, or wait till later to pick one) people like answering questions of people who pick correct answers

Comment: @Neal I'm sure all of these answers are correct in theory, but none of them are working for me. :(  If I choose a correct answer, doesn't that mean my issue is now non-existent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $("a.tab").click(function (e) {
```

In the code you are missing the `event argument variable` which in this case would be the `e`.

If you are suing preventDefault() method there is no need to use return false.

**online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dcFT7/

**UPDATE**

The scroll jump is not caused by the click on the link, it is caused because when the ul is hidden `$(".inside ul").fadeOut()` the page height gets smaller thus the browser scrolls to the top.

This i can be fixed by using `.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500)` to do the fadeOut effect without hiding it.

```
$("a.tab").click(function (e) {
    ...
    $(".inside ul").animate({opacity:0},500);
    $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: you dont need to include the event var, and i dont believe there is one for  click

Comment: @neal be my guest, try this demo taking out the "e" from "function(e){" and see if it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dcFT7/ **You have to declare it in the function arguments.**

Comment: @amosrivera, fine that may be. but i think it also has to do with the defauld being prevented at the rong space

Comment: @neal: if you want to access the event object (ie `e.preventDefault`) you do. However as you said in your answer... that call also needs to be first or at least before the `return false` statement. So you both have part of the answer :-)

Comment: fixed my answer to include `(e)`

Comment: @neal it is not "may be" it is that way, programming it's not about chances. @prodigutalson agree, anything you put after a return false won't execute, the point is he shouldn't be suing return false as he is already trying to use prevetDefault() which is the recommended method for this situations

Comment: @amosrivera I've added the (e), relocated the e.preventDefault, and removed the "return false".  I've even changed the anchor tags to list items.  However, there is no change in the page returning to top.  Any ideas?

Comment: I just saw your page, the problem is not caused by the click on the anchor, what happens it that when you hide the ul `$(".inside ul").fadeOut();` the page height gets smaller thus the browser scrolls to the top. Try adding `.inside ul{ display:block !important }` to the css that should fix it.

Comment: @SSHUC added a different alternative to my answer

Answer (score 1):

the trouble is ur returning before ur preventing the default action (`e.preventDefault();`), try this:

```
    $("a.tab").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".inside ul").fadeOut();
        $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        return false;
    });
```

and on the anchor tags make sure the href is of the form:

```
href='javascript:void(0);'
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.tab").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".inside ul").fadeOut();
    $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
    var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
    return false;
   });
   //$("a.tab, h4").FontEffect({
   // outline: true
  // })
  });

Comment: @SSHUC, see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be as simple as "e.preventDefault();" being on the wrong line?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.tab").click(function () {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".inside ul").fadeOut();
            $(".inside ul").fadeIn();
            var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
            return false;

        });
        $("a.tab, h4").FontEffect({
            outline: true
        })
    });
```